# Make a horizontally scrollable bootsrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a scrolling Row in boostrap.  This row encapsulates 5 or more columns, each of class "col-sm-3". Now I don't want the extra columns to collapse to next line, instead they should remain hidden until scrolled. 
Can someone please help on how to achieve this?  Here is the code,please see the simi

```html
<!-- listings -->
<div class="col-sm-10">

  <div class="row" style="overflow-x:visible; overflow-y:hidden; display:inline-block;">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="affiliate-frame text-center" id="product1">
        <a href="#">
          <img alt="" class="square-frame" src="images/product1-market.jpg">
        </a>

        <div class="padd-top-10 font-size-14">Casual T Shirt Black</div>

        <div class="padd-top-10 "><a href="#" class="lnk-affiliates"> AED 225 </a>
        </div>
        <div class="padd-top-10 ">
          <a href="#" class="lnk-affiliates"> <strong> Dubai, UAE </strong>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- affiliate frame -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="affiliate-frame text-center" id="product1">
        <a href="#">
          <img alt="" class="square-frame" src="images/product1-market.jpg">
        </a>

        <div class="padd-top-10 font-size-14">Casual T Shirt Black</div>

        <div class="padd-top-10 "><a href="#" class="lnk-affiliates"> AED 225 </a>
        </div>
        <div class="padd-top-10 ">
          <a href="#" class="lnk-affiliates"> <strong> Dubai, UAE </strong>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- affiliate frame -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="affiliate-frame text-center" id="product1">
        <a href="#">
          <img alt="" class="square-frame" src="images/product1-market.jpg">
        </a>

        <div class="padd-top-10 font-size-14">Casual T Shirt Black</div>

        <div class="padd-top-10 "><a href="#" class="lnk-affiliates"> AED 225 </a>
        </div>
        <div class="padd-top-10 ">
          <a href="#" class="lnk-affiliates"> <strong> Dubai, UAE </strong>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- affiliate frame -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="affiliate-frame text-center" id="product1">
        <a href="#">
          <img alt="" class="square-frame" src="images/product1-market.jpg">
        </a>

        <div class="padd-top-10 font-size-14">Casual T Shirt Black</div>

        <div class="padd-top-10 "><a href="#" class="lnk-affiliates"> AED 225 </a>
        </div>
        <div class="padd-top-10 ">
          <a href="#" class="lnk-affiliates"> <strong> Dubai, UAE </strong>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- affiliate frame -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="affiliate-frame text-center" id="product1">
        <a href="#">
          <img alt="" class="square-frame" src="images/product1-market.jpg">
        </a>

        <div class="padd-top-10 font-size-14">Casual T Shirt Black</div>

        <div class="padd-top-10 "><a href="#" class="lnk-affiliates"> AED 225 </a>
        </div>
        <div class="padd-top-10 ">
          <a href="#" class="lnk-affiliates"> <strong> Dubai, UAE </strong>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- affiliate frame -->
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- listings -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need `white-space:nowrap` on container and `float:none;display:inline-block` on each column

https://jsfiddle.net/g8138wjo/2/

Comment: Thank you sir! Works exactly how I want.